# Android Studio Play Store emulator adb unauthorized

Tags: android, adb, device, unauthorized

[Unauthorized - screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIo26.jpg)

I upgraded my Android Studio yesterday to the latest version (from 2.xx to 3.3) and created emulator devices using AVD. For some reason, the devices with "Play Store" support do not work. I tried it on my personal phone, it worked fine but testing different emulator CPUs (x86, x64), different android versions (24, 25, 26, 27, 28), the issue only happens with "Play Store" icon emulator devices (as in the screenshot). They appear as unauthorized in "adb devices". Any further messing with that device gives
***error: device unauthorized.
This adb server's $ADB_VENDOR_KEYS is not set***

I've tried the following things and none of them work.

1. Making the device a developer.
2. Revoking USB debugging settings.
3. Disabling and enabling USB debugging.
4. Changing the device's USB config to "File transfer".
5. Killing and starting adb server multiple times.
6. Wiping device data from AVD manager.
7. Cold booting the device from AVD manager.
8. Deleting and creating new devices.
9. Adding "ANDROID_SDK_ROOT" in environment variables, to Android Home's location.
10. Restarting my PC between all these different things.

My android studio's "About" is

> Android Studio 3.3 Build #AI-182.5107.16.33.5199772, built on December
>   25, 2018 JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01 amd64 JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit
>   Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o Windows 10 10.0

Comment: I uninstalled Android studio and manually deleted everything related and then did a clean re-install. After that, when creating a new device, the recommended section with playstore devices still don't work but the next section in the list ( available ones ) with playstore finally work. So I'm using those at the moment

Answer (score 0):

Short answer :platform-tools 28.0.2 has some braking changes with AVD and it will take may be 2 weeks more for them to fix the bug in stable channel. Fix is available in canary channel already

Please find detailed answer in below link.

https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/b35cgl/psa_do_not_use_platformtools_2802_with_the